# I need to create a hierarchy json like the given structure from array of object as datasource having a single word as input

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraylist, linked-list

I am facing problem in creating a hierarchy of json from the data source. The use case is if I run node app.js “term". It should create a structure like "term.json" given below. From the datasource.js.
It looks like linked list problem.

I also want to minimize the number of calls to the datasource module and maintain the async nature of code.

*Datasource.js*

```
const internalData = {
    "term": [
        "quantity",
        "constituent"
    ],
    "quantity": [
        "amount",
        "concept"
    ],
    "constituent": [
        "syntagma",
        "voter"
    ],
    "amount": [
        "magnitude"
    ],
    "artificial_intelligence": [
        "computer_science"
    ],
    "science": [
        "subject",
        "method_to_understand_world",
        "discipline"
    ],
    "syntagma": [
        "string_of_words"
    ],
    "concept": [
        "idea"
    ],
    "voter": [
        "citizen"
    ],
    "asteroid": [
        "celestial_body"
    ],
    "celestial_body": [
        "natural_object"
    ],
    "natural_object": [
        "whole"
    ],
    "whole": [],
    "string_of_words": [
        "language",
        "string"
    ],
    "magnitude": [
        "importance",
        "property"
    ],
    "idea": [
        "central_meaning_purpose_or_concept",
        "opinion",
        "content"
    ],
    "citizen": [
        "national"
    ],
    "language": [],
    "string": [
        "series"
    ],
    "central_meaning_purpose_or_concept": [],
    "importance": [
        "value",
        "standing"
    ],
    "opinion": [
        "message"
    ],
    "property": [
        "object",
        "concept"
    ],
    "series": [
        "polynomial"
    ],
    "standing": [
        "motion"
    ],
    "content": [
        "proportion",
        "cognition"
    ],
    "rocket": [
        "machine",
        "visual_signal",
        "vehicle"
    ],
    "visual_signal": [
        "signal"
    ],
    "machine": [],
    "vehicle": [
        "substance",
        "medium"
    ],
    "signal": [
        "communication",
        "incitement"
    ],
    "medium": [
        "transmission",
        "substance",
        "environment"
    ],
    "substance": [],
    "incitement": [
        "psychic_energy"
    ],
    "communication": [
        "act"
    ],
    "psychic_energy": [
        "motivation"
    ],
    "transmission": [
        "sending",
        "communication"
    ],
    "environment": [
        "situation",
        "geographical_area"
    ],
    "motivation": [
        "psychological_feature",
        "act"
    ],
    "sending": [
        "causing",
        "directed_movement",
        "loss_of_user_rights"
    ],
    "psychological_feature": [
        "abstraction"
    ],
    "directed_movement": [
        "moving",
        "controlling_event"
    ],
    "act": [],
    "loss_of_user_rights": [
        "issuing",
        "change_in_user_rights"
    ],
    "saturn": [
        "planet",
        "american_car",
        "car"
    ],
    "american_car": [
        "car",
        "gas_driven_automobile"
    ],
    "planet": [
        "large_object",
        "celestial_body"
    ],
    "large_object": [],
    "gas_driven_automobile": [
        "gas_powered_road_vehicle",
        "car"
    ],
    "car": [
        "vehicle",
        "motor_vehicle"
    ],
    "gas_powered_road_vehicle": [],
    "motor_vehicle": [
        "self_propelled_vehicle",
        "land_vehicle"
    ],
    "self_propelled_vehicle": [
        "wheeled_vehicle"
    ],
    "land_vehicle": [
        "self_powered_vehicle",
        "land_transportation_device"
    ],
    "self_powered_vehicle": [
        "user_guided_device",
        "transportation_device",
        "self_powered_device",
        "consumer_durable"
    ],
    "wheeled_vehicle": [
        "container",
        "vehicle",
        "land_transportation_device"
    ],
    "land_transportation_device": [
        "hexalateral_object",
        "terrestrial_functioning_object",
        "transportation_device",
        "consumer_durable"
    ],
    "geographical_area": [
        "region"
    ],
    "situation": [],
    "causing": [
        "act",
        "action"
    ],
    "abstraction": [
        "concept",
        "painting",
        "entity"
    ],
    "controlling_event": [],
    "change_in_user_rights": [
        "change_of_property_holdings",
        "human_activity"
    ],
    "issuing": [
        "writing",
        "transfer"
    ],
    "moving": [],
    "region": [
        "indefinite_quantity",
        "location"
    ],
    "action": [],
    "painting": [
        "fine_arts",
        "trade"
    ],
    "value": [],
    "message": [],
    "national": [
        "person"
    ],
    "motion": [],
    "object": [
        "thing",
        "computer_science"
    ],
    "polynomial": [
        "mapping"
    ],
    "proportion": [
        "magnitude_relation"
    ],
    "cognition": [
        "psychological_feature"
    ],
    "thing": [
        "situation"
    ],
    "magnitude_relation": [
        "relation",
        "relationship"
    ],
    "computer_science": [
        "science"
    ],
    "black": [
        "color"
    ],
    "color": [
        "timbre",
        "visual_property"
    ],
    "visual_property": [
        "property"
    ],
    "timbre": [
        "sound_property"
    ],
    "sound_property": [
        "property"
    ],
    "method_to_understand_world": [],
    "discipline": [],
    "subject": [],
    "mapping": [
        "mathematical_relation",
        "procedure"
    ],
    "person": []
};

module.exports = class Data {

    getTerm(term) {
        return internalData[term] ? internalData[term] : null;
    }
};

Term.json:


 {
      "relation": {
        "magnitude_relation": {
          "proportion": {
            "content": {
              "idea": {
                "concept": {
                  "quantity": {
                    "term": {}
                  },
                  "property": {
                    "magnitude": {
                      "amount": {
                        "quantity": {
                          "term": {}
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: You have circular references in your data - how do you expect to resolve those?

Comment: It is not very important to have the same result as given in term.json. The result can vary slightly. It will reach at some point with null value.

Comment: While that may be, the algorithm you seem to be looking for requires a tree that you "go up" finding parents until you hit a root/top level where there is a "null" value.  But if you have circular references, then you would have an infinite loop that won't "reach at some point with null value".  So again, what are your requirements regarding any circular references?

Comment: Your point is right..I was thinking this a problem of graph query..where I can get exact structure without. What do you reckon?

Comment: I have code for this problem, but you would need to decide about the circular reference problem in order for me to complete it and post an answer.  One approach is to treat circular references as invalid input and just throw an exception or return an error.  But if your data is valid for such references, then the solution will need to decide what to do when it hits one.  You could have the output mark the circular reference and stop there and continue with the next branch.  Really this is a requirements problem, not a coding problem.

Comment: Hi, @DDupont I will really like to see your solution. For circular references. We can check for the next branch if any. If not, we can throw an error then.

Comment: Hi @DDupont. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Sorry to leave you hanging Ayush.  I am in the middle of a security audit and have been swamped. I will try to get to it again soon when my day job permits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my prototype code for an algorithm as you describe.  It includes a check for a circular reference which you can modify to do what you think is correct (I would throw an exception if that should not happen).  I have left lots of debugging that needs to be cleaned up so you can see what it does dynamically.  You should also look into how to modularize this and avoid the globals:

```
var util = require('util');
var index = {};
function mkIndex() {
    Object.keys(internalData).map(function(term) {
        internalData[term].map(function(relation) {
            index[relation] = index[relation] || [];
            index[relation].push(term)
        })
    })
}

function getTerm(term, depth, parents) {
    var result = {}
    parents = parents || [];
    depth = (depth || 0) + 1;
    console.log(`find ${term}, ${depth}`)
    if (parents.indexOf(term) >= 0) {
        result = { 'CircularRef': term, parents: parents};
        console.log(`return ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
        return result;
    }
    if (depth > 16) {
        result = { 'ERROR': 'ERROR'}
        console.log(`return ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
        return result;
    }
    parents.push(term);
    var relations = index[term]
    if (relations) {
        relations.map(function(relation) {
            result[relation] = getTerm(relation, depth, parents);
        })
    }
    parents.pop();
    console.log(`return ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
    return result;
}

mkIndex();
console.log(`\n\n\n${util.inspect(getTerm("relation"),false,30)}`);
```